# Prove minimum vertex bisection problem is reducible from bisection width, thereby proving NP-Completeness

Tags: np-complete, decision-problem, polynomial-time-reductions, minimum-cuts, max-cut

The bisection width problem gives you a yes or a no -> if there exists a bisection of size at most $K$ for $G=V,E$.

Minimum Vertex Bisection problem gives you a bisection of the smallest size.

Bisection Width is NP-Complete, I want to prove Minimum Vertex Bisection is also NP-Complete by deriving a reduction from Bisection Width

I've seen the Max-cut to Max Bisection problem where the reduction happens by adding vertices. I was thinking of approaching it in a similar fashion

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4423410/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150511/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: "I want to prove Minimum Vertex Bisection is also NP-Complete." Since "Minimum Vertex Bisection" is not [a decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem), it is not even [an NP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)). Do you mean "I want to prove Minimum Vertex Bisection is NP-hard"?